# Reading in an ascii extended character

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem reading in a extended ASCII character and converting it to it's decimal value. I tried doing this:

```
unsigned char temp;
while(temp = cin.get != EOF)
{
cout << (int)temp << endl;
}
```

but then all it prints out is the number 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

`while(temp = cin.get() != EOF)`.

You are assigning `temp` the truth value of `cin.get() != EOF`. Until EOF is encountered, you will only see `1` as output.

Changing it to:
`while((temp = cin.get()) != EOF)`.

will give you more closely what you are expecting.